# Converting string to Uri for Picasso (Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, picasso

I am creating a simple Android app where the user adds cryptocurrencies to a list. One of the variables in the data model is an image. The type of variable is String. I am doing it this way as I am saving all added cryptos to Firestore, but for the image to load in the app, it must be converted to a Uri.

```
var image: String = "",
```

In my activity, I have created a variable where I convert the variable to a Uri, like so:

```
var imageUri: Uri = Uri.parse(crypto.image)
```

In my onCreate() in the activity, I am passing in this new variable to Picasso.

```
Picasso.get()
     .load(imageUri)
     .into(binding.cryptoImage)
if (imageUri != Uri.EMPTY) {
    binding.chooseImage.setText(R.string.change_crypto_image)
}
```

There is also a registerImagePickerCallback() function that is called in the onCreate().

```
private fun registerImagePickerCallback() {
    imageIntentLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
        { result ->
            when(result.resultCode){
                RESULT_OK -> {
                    if (result.data != null) {
                        i("Got Result ${result.data!!.data}")
                        imageUri = result.data!!.data!!
                        Picasso.get()
                            .load(imageUri)
                            .into(binding.cryptoImage)
                        binding.chooseImage.setText(R.string.change_crypto_image)
                    } // end of if
                }
                RESULT_CANCELED -> { } else -> { }
            }
        }
}
```

When adding the cryptocurrency item, it adds to Firestore (with image = ""), and adds to the ListActivity in the App, but the image does not appear and the app crashes. There is also the following error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.wit.cryptocurrency, PID: 16474
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter it
    at org.wit.cryptocurrency.activities.CryptocurrencyActivity.firestoreUpload$lambda-5(Unknown Source:2)
    at org.wit.cryptocurrency.activities.CryptocurrencyActivity.$r8$lambda$uuGRAf9JOGKvuGRTbhiS1a-6Pfg(Unknown Source:0)
    at org.wit.cryptocurrency.activities.CryptocurrencyActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda8.onSuccess(Unknown Source:2)
```

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: `One of the variables in the data model is an image. The type of variable is String. ` That i do not understand. One does not hold images in strings. Well normally not. Please explain what you mean by that. A complete jpg file in a a string?

Comment: I am not given a specific line, but I believe it to be where the firestoreUpload() function is being called in the onCreate().

    private fun firestoreUpload() {
        firestore.collection("cryptos").document(crypto.name)
            .set(crypto)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                i("DocumentSnapshot added")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                i(e, "Error adding document")
            }
    }

Comment: Apologies, I should have said that the image PATH is being saved as a string in the model, not the actual file.